# Making a background-image clickable by overlaying hyperlink?

Tags: html, css

I want to give the impression that a logo is clickable even if the logo is a background image. I am unable to edit HTML, so I can only edit CSS(this is for a blog hosted at Wordpress.com, so they do not let you edit the HTML).

The current theme has a text link that links back to the home page (this is the same link that I want the background image to link to). I have used CSS to make the background of the homepage link the image of the logo. So, right now, I have the background image behind the homepage link text the image of the logo.

Now, is there anyway to hide the text while retaining the link status so it gives the illusion that a visitor can click on the logo(even though they are really clicking on the invisible text)? I tried to add "text-indent: -9999px" to the style of the homepage link, and it correctly hides the homepage link text, but it does not retain the link status.

Comment: Make it an `<img>`. Backgrounds are backgrounds, they aren't supposed to communicate anything important (such as "click here").

Comment: Can't do it. Wordpress.com does not allow me to edit the HTML.

Comment: Please, post html you have and make a picture to show, what exact result you want to reach. This discussion would be much shorter, if the task were clear.

Answer (score 3):

Logo links are usually made with such code:

```
.link {
  display: block; /* or display: inline-block; */
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -999px;
}
```

Comment: The text-indent makes the logo text completely disappear.

Comment: i would use something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/JytJq/1/ ( overflow isnt bad idea though.. )

Comment: @egidra just write your logo text on the image itself. Html text is for search engines only, when using text-indent property.

Comment: @Webars I think that is the point, but the link in that title where the html text exists is the only thing he can really use cause he cant edit the html. By the way html text is also for screen readers.

Comment: @Webars, actually it's for accessibility, not for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `<area>` tag might be a good idea, but you'll have to display your logo as an `<img>`.

See http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_area.asp for an example

Basically, you define an area within an image that acts as a link. You even give it an `href` value. That seems much nicer than trying to make some invisible text.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot do this as Wordpress.com does not allow me to edit the HTML, only the CSS, so I changed the background of the header tag to be the new logo.

Answer (score 1):

If the text inside the `a` tag is wrapped in another tag (such as a `span` tag) this would be possible:

```
a span { visibility: hidden; }
```

This would hide the text while still showing the image. Alternatively, I do believe wordpress.com does allow you to toggle the text on/off for the header of most themes (I may be wrong here though). Go to Appearance > Header > and see if the Diaplay Text option is there.

Answer (score 1):

Before you read below, I also agree with Quentin that it needs to be made into an . Bad programming practice trying to hack around this:

---

Can you edit the HTML for where the anchor tag exists? You need to embed another tag within the anchor.. ex:

```
<a href="PATHTOHOMEPAGE"> <h1>Text Link Back to home</h1> </a>
```

From there, within the CSS, you can hide the H1 tag within the anchor tag as follows:

```
a h1 {display: none;}
```

This will only hide the H1 content, leaving the anchor still on the page.

But all this also relies on if the anchor lives within a DIV element or something that specifically sizes around the logo. If so, you need to set the anchor CSS as:

```
a {display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

This makes the anchor the full width and height of its parent element, which should be the DIV that also has the logo as your background image.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/JytJq/3/

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="BG">Home</a>
```

CSS:

```
.BG {  
    text-indent: -99999px;
    background: url("http://lorempixum.com/400/200/") no-repeat top left;
    float: left;   
    overflow: hidden;

    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
```